# Boot into Big Sur/Catalina from Mojave WITHOUT keyboard access?

Tags: catalina, mojave, startup, big-sur

I've got a separate Mojave boot partition on my headless Mac Mini running Big Sur.

Under `System Preferences > Startup Disk` I can select the boot disk and restart into Mojave from Catalina or now Big Sur. However due to changes made in Catalina/Big Sur, their startup partitions are not detected in Mojave's `System Preferences > Startup Disk`.

Unfortunately starting into Mojave from the `Startup Disk` panel changes the default boot disk to the Mojave disk and all subsequent restarts load Mojave.

I can restart into the Big Sur holding down option on restart to bring up the boot loader, but this requires I hook up a keyboard (and often a monitor, otherwise it's a bit of a pain without).

**Question:** Is there any command or startup parameter I can set from inside Mojave to have the computer boot into Big Sur?

**Alternatively:** Is there any way to boot into Mojave from Big Sur without a keyboard and without changing the default startup disk?

Comment: You could install a different boot manager such as rEFInd. You then would instruct the firmware to first boot rEFInd. However, the problem is when you install certain updates to macOS, the default to boot may be changed back to macOS instead of rEFInd. You then would have to boot to macOS Recovery or the Mac Startup Manager to change the default back to rEFInd.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, great suggestion, thanks. Though I'm looking for a solution that won't ever require me hooking up a keyboard (or monitor).